# Trying to make autoscroll textarea user selectable via checkbox but is working inconsistently

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am coding in javascript and want to autoscroll a textArea, moving the scroll bar to the bottom as new data is added.  This works but if I try to check if a checkbox is checked or not and enable or disable that feature based upon that.  At 1st it appears to work, it auto scrolls when the checkbox is checked, and stop when unchecked.  But, once I uncheck it will never go back to auto scrolling again. Also, it seems to fail over time even if I don't uncheck it.   To me it seems the problem must have something to do with the portion where I call document.getElementById('autoscroll').checked

Very inconsistent. Below is the relevant HTML and javascript code.  Any light you can shed on this would be appreciated.

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="autoscroll" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="autoscroll">Autoscroll</label>
</div>

<script>
    const messageArea = document.getElementById("message-area");
    const filterInput = document.getElementById("filter-input");
    const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://YourWebsocketServer:5000?filename=${filename}`);

    filterInput.addEventListener("input", event => {
            const filterText = event.target.value;
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "filter", filterText }));
    });

    socket.addEventListener("message", event => {
            const message = event.data;
            messageArea.value = message;
            
            if (document.getElementById('autoscroll').checked === false) {
                messageArea.scrollTop = messageArea.scrollHeight;
            }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was just a typo.

I had the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('autoscroll').checked === false)
```

and replaced it with

```
if (document.getElementById('autoscroll').checked === true)
```

and it works now.  My bad.